# error while parsing SOAP

Tags: ios, objective-c, soapui

I am calling soap web service which results in the following error:

```
DONE. Received Bytes: 156
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Web Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Bad Request</H1><PRE>Error parsing envelope: &#40;3, 13&#41; Whitespace required.</PRE></BODY></HTML>
```

I am using the following is my code:

```
        -(IBAction)invokeService
    {
            NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                                    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:dpw=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/\n" "xmlns:dpw1=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/dpw_create_absence_api/\">\n"
                                    "<soapenv:Header>  <dpw:SOAHeader>   <!--Optional:--><dpw:Responsibility></dpw:Responsibility> <!--Optional:-->                                <dpw:RespApplication></dpw:RespApplication><!--Optional:--><dpw:SecurityGroup></dpw:SecurityGroup> <!--Optional:--><dpw:NLSLanguage></dpw:NLSLanguage>                               <!--Optional:-->  <dpw:Org_Id></dpw:Org_Id> </dpw:SOAHeader> </soapenv:Header>       <soapenv:Body>    <dpw1:InputParameters>                               <!--Optional:-->  <dpw1:PERSON_ID>2</dpw1:PERSON_ID>  </dpw1:InputParameters> </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope>"];


            NSLog(@"The request format is %@",soapFormat);

            NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oracle.techvedika.com:8006/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/"];
            NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

            NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

            NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

            [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [theRequest addValue:@"http://oracle.techvedika.com:8006/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
            [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
            [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

            if (connect)
            {
                webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
                startActivityIndicator;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"No Connection established");
            }
    }

    //NSURLConnection delegate method

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        [webData setLength: 0];
    }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        [webData appendData:data];
    }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
        [connection release];
        [webData release];
    }
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
        NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webData];
        [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
        //[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
        [xmlParser parse];
    }

//xml delegates

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

}
```

in connectionDidFinishLoading I am getting 156 bytes of NSDATA when I convert it to string it is giving the above error. Where am I going wrong?

When I tested the URL in Soapclient UI I got the o/p As follows I am attaching screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up with double quote in your request. Use below instead.

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:dpw=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/\"\n xmlns:dpw1=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/dpw_create_absence_pkg/dpw_create_absence_api/\">\n"
                             "<soapenv:Header>  <dpw:SOAHeader>   <!--Optional:--><dpw:Responsibility></dpw:Responsibility> <!--Optional:-->                                <dpw:RespApplication></dpw:RespApplication><!--Optional:--><dpw:SecurityGroup></dpw:SecurityGroup> <!--Optional:--><dpw:NLSLanguage></dpw:NLSLanguage>                               <!--Optional:-->  <dpw:Org_Id></dpw:Org_Id> </dpw:SOAHeader> </soapenv:Header>       <soapenv:Body>    <dpw1:InputParameters>                               <!--Optional:-->  <dpw1:PERSON_ID>2</dpw1:PERSON_ID>  </dpw1:InputParameters> </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope>"];
```

Comment: thank u so much.but the O/P is <env:Envelope xmlns:env="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">; <env:Header/> <env:Body><env:Fault xmlns:wsse="docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/…; <faultcode xmlns="">wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode> <faultstring xmlns="">Missing &lt;wsse:Security&gt; in SOAP Header</faultstring><faultactor xmlns=""> </faultactor></env:Fault> </env:Body></env:Envelope> how do i fix this?   is this specific to IOS?